# Is there any way to group cases?

Tags: civicase, groups, tags

Is there any way to group cases, other than using tags? 
We currently need this for an implementation where case management is used to fulfill wishes for children with chronic diseases. The organization has cases where they need to organize events on a high level for a whole group of children (booking hotels, travel planning etc.) and do some of the planning individually per child with a very different set of activities (communication with parents, getting authorizations etc.). I feel that tags are not sufficient in this case and I would prefer to have a parent case with child cases assigned to it - or at least a group so we would have better selection options in the system. But groups are only available for contacts (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything exactly like what you're looking for. You can set a case as related to another case, so your parent case could be related to all its child cases. On Manage Case add an activity of type "Link Case", and then on both Manage Case screens that linkage will appear.

Comment: Thanks, that might be a good solution to look into... We'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks again for this very useful hint! :) I tried it out on a sandbox system and it seems to work well. However, one more question for reporting purposes: where is this link between cases stored? I have searched all tables in the database referring to cases or activities, but could not find the reference between the two cases that I joined...

Comment: Found it! It's linked only via civicrm_case_activity. Unfortunately, this makes it difficult to access the data structures for reports... Seems like this functionality needs some further "refinement".

Answer (score 0):

You can add Custom Fields on Cases. It may not be a lot of hard work to have a Custom 'reference' field created that lets you link one case to another, but I haven't verified that with our tech experts

Comment: There seems to be no need for custom fields, although that was also something we had considered in the beginning. As soon as you activate the CiviCase component, there is a standard activity called "Link Cases" that comes with the module. Using that activity, you can link cases together (unfortunately, this is not documented in the user guide...). Still trying to find out how exactly they are linked together. See my comment above to Demerit above.

Comment: Right. but as far as I know the Link Cases Activity does not actually give a 'link' in the sense that you can click on it and go through to the other case, in the way that a Contact Reference field does. I was imagining you wanted something more like the latter

Comment: You can click on it and go to the other case but as andrea notes it's hard to report on using native civi functions.

Comment: odd. i tested on a site with case but didn't get linked through. ah ha retried and now i see a "1 Related Case" up at top of the Case screen. that makes more sense.

Comment: Exactly... not easy to find, but it is there... And as petednz commented, reporting is almost not available.